# should i remove row from table or just disable that row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In all project I realize, I add in each table a field named `disabled ( true, false )`

If the user click on "delete", the row just turn disabled to false

For don't have any problem on cascade delete

I just wanna know if this method is good or there are another method?

Comment: This method is fine.  How you delete records should be based on the requirements of the system your are producing, and your method is quite valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends entirely on the application. In many cases there is legal requirements to retain financial information for all orders even if the customer is deleted. A disabled flag is the right thing in that case. That will retain the historical data intact.

In some cases (especially under EU privacy laws) it might be necessary to "detach" the disabled customer record from any physical person. That can be done by wiping all personal information in the record on the same time as setting the disabled flag. That way you can know that customer 4711 ordered some stuff at various occasions, but you can no longer know who that customer was.

Comment: thanks for your post , so if i understend , the best way is what i do if i'm creating a E-Commerce app ?

Comment: Use disabled flag, but also wipe all personally identifiable columns (name, address etc.) on the customer record when you set the disabled flag. Unless you have legal requirements to keep records of stuff sold. There is often a very narrow path between breaking the legal requirements for book-keeping and those for privacy.